# How do i get the most used word in a range of cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I trying to do that using a formula found on the web

INDEX(A1:A30, MATCH(A1:A30;A1:A30,0)))

which doesn't seem to work, because it finds different words depending on where the formula is copied . Where am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: Just a list of arbitrary strings, no special chars (as far as i can tell, i don't see any of them). Anyway here it is:

```
Guangzhou Evergrande
Guangzhou Evergrande
Shanghai Shenhua
Shanghai Shenhua
Chongqing Lifan
Shanghai Shenhua
Shanghai Shenhua
Shandong Luneng
Shanghai Shenhua
Tianjin Tianhai
Shanghai Shenhua
Shanghai Shenhua
Beijing Renhe
Shanghai Shenhua
Hebei
Shanghai SIPG
Shanghai Shenhua
Jiangsu Suning
Beijing Guoan
Shanghai Shenhua
Dalian Pro
Shanghai Shenhua
Tianjin Teda
Shenzhen
Shanghai Shenhua
Wuhan Zall
Guangzhou R&F
Shanghai Shenhua
Henan Jianye
Shanghai Shenhua
Shanghai Shenhua
```

Expected output: Shangai Shenhua.

Comment: Some test data and expected output would help.

Comment: It's just a contiguos range of cells (a column to be precise) of text type, containing arbitrary words, some of which are repeated one or more times. Id like to get the most used word.

Comment: One word per cell?

Comment: yes, only a word per cell. Well, a word with spaces, it's more a name then a word, but ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the Match in Mode.Sngl

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$31,MODE.SNGL(MATCH($A$1:$A$31,$A$1:$A$31,0)))
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Note this requires the Cells to be identical.

[image]

---

If the list is dynamic (unknown number of items) or can have blanks in the list itself we need to account for that:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MODE.SNGL(IF($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A))<>"",MATCH($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)),A:A,0))))
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: I'm getting #N/A error code, even when confirming with ctrl+shift+enter. Anyway i do need something more "dynamic" while this formula, if i'm not wrong, it's a bit static. I'd like the search to happen anytime the underlying list of words changes.

Comment: It will update as the data changes.  But if you are getting N/A, either you are entering wrong or there are no true duplicates.  So we are back to needing more information from you, like test data that mimics your data.  Also what version you are using and so on.

Comment: I copy pasted your list and it came up with the correct output without changing anything.

Comment: yeah, that's because I forgot to mention that there may be spaces at the bottom of the list. Maybe I can fix this using the OFFSET () function. Anyway now it shows the correct word, thanks.

Comment: You did not specify that there could be blank rows at the bottom.  This does require that there be no blanks in the range.

Comment: I know, it was my mistake, sorry

Comment: is the list complete, as in no empty cells in the list, you just want to refer to the whole column?

Comment: OK, it works now. Thank, you. Just a curiosity: what's the use for the "zzz" in both match functions?

Comment: `MATCH("zzz",A:A)` basically returns the last row where there is text.  `"zzz"` is just something to search for that would be the last alphabetically.

Comment: I see. Thank you again.